# Dual boot problem after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi

During the upgrade to 16.04 something went wrong (related to shim-signed and problems with /boot/efi) and it was not completed. After some work I managed to have everything installed and Ubuntu seems to work fine now. However, along the way I lost the possibility to boot my Windows 8 installation. When I choose that option in grub it says that it cannot find the corresponding drive.
The output from efibootmgr indicates (I guess) that everything is correct

```
BootCurrent: 0008
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0008,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,000A,0007,0009
Boot0000  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0001  Boot Menu FvFile(86488440-41bb-42c7-93ac-450fbf7766bf)
Boot0002* Removable Drive   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,20699b27e1a34f488e97534d40523c1d)
Boot0003* Hard Drive    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,f5b01cc8ce8e9841b3a8fb94b6dfefee)
Boot0004* USB Storage Device    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6895f49a99882e4bb0da03ec784d2828)
Boot0005* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,3750dce1249e1748876bee5d3f25ebfb)
Boot0006* Network   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6567de8ee595634d842b325e6a43510b)
Boot0007* Network Boot  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,1b7f7356e3475744a9a6ed8e91832083)
Boot0008* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,b032ab5d-1a06-4b52-afcb-14954b4b6ab8,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
Boot0009  Change boot mode setting  FvFile(be77e3c1-eb5a-4a5d-897f-536e8b3c74c0)
Boot000A* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,b032ab5d-1a06-4b52-afcb-14954b4b6ab8,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...H................
```

My fstab file looks as follows:

```
# / was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=5cc07bc2-7247-40b6-8290-7edef8b4a39d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda9 during installation
#UUID=b22addc5-b969-47bf-a154-f91b6a137dd6 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda11 during installation
UUID=0aa517c8-aed2-446f-91c2-ecb573598a6d /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
#UUID=64342e46-54ea-46bf-826e-5667367e2301 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
UUID=b22addc5-b969-47bf-a154-f91b6a137dd6   /boot   ext4    defaults    0   2
UUID=5251-F902  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
#UUID=b032ab5d-1a06-4b52-afcb-14954b4b6ab8  /boot/efi   /dev/sda1: PARTLABEL=   defaults    0   1
```

Any idea regarding where I should start? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions, neither of which is guaranteed to work:

- **Run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)** -- This tool can fix many boot problems more-or-less automatically. If you run it, be sure to run it from your working Ubuntu install or from an emergency disk booted in the *same way* (that is, in EFI mode, if your output is any indication). The down side to this approach is that, on rare occasion, it actually makes matters worse. Such problems are rare, but you should be prepared for the possibility.
- **Install my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com)** -- This program can sometimes boot Windows when GRUB can't, and is therefore worth trying. You can do this in relative safety by trying the USB flash drive or CD-R image before installing it to your hard disk; however, this will require that you disable Secure Boot, at least temporarily, if it's currently enabled. Also, if Secure Boot is active, rEFInd will require you to register a key when it first boots. In this case, I also recommend you install the Debian-package version, *not* the PPA, because of [a bug in Ubuntu 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sbsigntool/+bug/1574372) that affects the way the PPA handles Secure Boot.

Your problem could be caused by an accidental deletion of the Windows boot loader. If that's the case, neither of the above solutions will work, and the only repair options involve using a Windows recovery disk or restoring the EFI System Partition's (ESP's) files from a backup. You can check for the relevant files in Ubuntu by typing:

```
sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot
```

There should be several files in that directory, including `bootmgfw.efi` (the main boot loader) and a number of others. If that file is not present, I recommend you investigate this detail further before you attempt either the Boot Repair or the rEFInd fix.

Comment: Thanks. The files in the /boot/efi folder seem to be all there. I am reluctant to use boot-repair because I have seen stories of systems becoming unbootable as a result.